# Zeichensetzung bei „zu“-Nebensätzen nach „dass“

Tags: punctuation, infinitive, subordinate-clause

Ich bin mir nicht sicher, wie/ob ich die Kommata in Sätzen wie dem folgenden setzen soll:

> Ich selbst wäre niemals auf die Idee gekommen, dass, sich vollständig aufrichten zu können, ein Luxus sein könnte.

Insbesondere das Komma nach dem „dass“ kommt mir seltsam vor, aber AFAIK müssen Infinitivgruppen mit Kommata abgetrennt werden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Die Kommas, die die Infinitivgruppe betreffen, sind optional.

Das erkennt man leichter, wenn man den Nebensatz alleinstehend betrachtet.

> Sich vollständig aufrichten zu können(,) könnte ein Luxus sein.

Muss hier das Komma gesetzt werden? Es gibt drei Regeln, die ein Komma erzwingen.

1. Die Infinitivgruppe wird mit *als*, *um*, *(an)statt*, *außer*, *ohne* eingeleitet. Ist hier offensichtlich nicht der Fall.
2. Die Infinitivgruppe wird angekündigt oder wieder aufgegriffen. Das trifft in deinem Beispiel auch nicht zu. Das sähe wie folgt aus:

   > **Es** könnte ein Luxus sein, sich vollständig aufrichten zu können.
   >   Sich vollständig aufrichten zu können, **das** könnte ein Luxus sein.
3. Die Infinitivgruppe ist von einem Nomen abhängig. Das könnte man auf den ersten Blick annehmen, dann müsste es aber etwa so aussehen:

   > Der Luxus, sich vollständig aufrichten zu können, ...

Da keine der Regeln greift, muss kein Komma gesetzt werden. Aber man kann. Aufgrund des doppelten "Könnens" würde ich es machen, bei der Verwendung des Indikativs würde ich es weglassen.

> Sich vollständig aufrichten zu können ist ein Luxus.
>   Sich vollständig aufrichten zu können, könnte ein Luxus sein.

Man hätte noch einfacher dort ankommen können. Die Infintivgruppe entspricht dem Subjekt und in dem Fall ist das Komma optional.

Anders sieht es aus, wenn man das "zu" weglässt. Dann ist das Komma falsch.

> Sich vollständig aufrichten können ist ein Luxus.
>   Sich vollständig aufrichten können könnte ein Luxus sein.

Siehe dazu auch [canoonet](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Interpunktion/Komma/PartAdjInf.html#Anchor-Infinitivgruppen-49575) als auch den [Blog von Canoonet](https://blog.canoonet.eu/2016/04/05/kommas-richtig-setzen-ist-nicht-immer-einfach-infinitivgruppen-als-subjekt/).

---

Anders sieht es mit dem Komma vor *dass* aus. Ein Komma, das den mit *dass* eingeleiteten Nebensatz abtrennt, ist zwingend obligatorisch.
Auch hierzu gibt es aber eine Handvoll scheinbarer 'Ausnahmen'.

1. Ist das *dass* Bestandteil einer mehrteiligen Einleitung, so steht das Komma vor dem gesamten Ausdruck, nicht jedoch unmittelbar vor dem *dass*.
2. Ist der Nebensatz Teil einer gleichrangigen Aufzählung, wird nur der erste Nebensatz mit einem Komma abgetrennt. Die Nebensätze, die mit beispielsweise *und* oder *oder* angebunden werden, erhalten kein zusätzliches Komma.

---

Zusammengefasst gibt es zwei Möglichkeiten für deinen Satz. Ein Komma oder drei Kommata.

> Ich selbst wäre niemals auf die Idee gekommen, dass sich vollständig aufrichten zu können ein Luxus sein könnte.
>
> Ich selbst wäre niemals auf die Idee gekommen, dass, sich vollständig aufrichten zu können, ein Luxus sein könnte.

Answer (score 0):

> sich vollständig aufrichten zu können

ist eine sogenannte *Infinitivgruppe*, welche nach der deutschen Rechtschreibung per Komma abgetrennt werden.

> dass [xxx] ein Luxus sein könnte

ist offensichtlich ein *Nebensatz*, welcher ebenfalls auch mit einem Komma abgetrennt wird.

**Deine Kommasetzungen stimmen also.**

Faustregeln:

- Wenn du dir nicht sicher bist, kannst du auch deinem Gefühl folgen und ein Komma setzen, wenn du beim Sprechen eine Pause machen würdest. Das hat eine hohe Trefferquote.
- Falls du Mathe-affin bist, kannst du dir auch Kommata als Klammern vorstellen. Der Teil, welcher Subjekt oder Objekt des Satzes sein sollte, aber eigentlich aus mehreren Worten besteht, wie z.B. Infinitivgruppen, wird einfach in "Klammern" zusammengefasst, also in Kommata.

Comment: Infinitivgruppen allgemein betrachtet **können** mit einem Komma abgetrennt werden. Es gibt einige Fälle in denen **müssen** sie abgetrennt werden. Wenn sie mit "um", "als" etc. eingeleitet werden, wenn sie von einem Nomen abhängig sind, wenn sie angekündigt oder wieder aufgegriffen werden. # Auch wenn eine Pause ein guter Indikator für ein Komma ist, werden im Deutschen häufig zu viele Kommata gesetzt. Die Klammer-Theorie finde ich zweifelhaft. Wenn man sich unsicher ist, sollte man eventuell den Satz umformulieren. "..., dass es ein Luxus sein Könnte, sich vollständig aufrichten zu können."

Comment: Du hast natürlich Recht. Man sollte *können* und *müssen* unterschieden. In beiden Fällen macht man keinen Fehler, wenn man eines setzt. Unabhängig davon: In Fällen, in denen man ein Komma setzen *kann*, wird es vom Duden empfohlen eines zu setzen, wenn dadurch die Lesbarkeit erhöht wird. Auf das zielen meine Faustregeln ab.

Comment: In deinem Beispiel haut's netterweise hin. Aber genau diese Daumenregel ist Grund für viele falsche Kommas.

Comment: *Kommata ;-) Schön jemanden kennen zu lernen, der sich noch mehr damit beschäftigt hat als ich. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Ja, streng nach der Regel muß dieses Komma sein. Eben deshalb ist die Verwendung des expletiven "es" so verbreitet:

> Ich selbst wäre niemals auf die Idee gekommen, dass es ein Luxus sein könnte, sich vollständig aufrichten zu können.

Damit erfüllt man gleichzeitig streng die Regel zur Zeichensetzung (bzw. Intonation in der gesprochenen Sprache) und muß trotzdem keine zwei unbequem eng aufeinanderfolgenden Zäsuren einsetzen.